# Styling Table to behave like divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins

I have a problem. I have done my homework and looked on-line for alternative solution but I couldn't find one that really fixed my problem.  I know people will ask why I want to make table behave like divs whereas I could just use div alone.

Well my issue is that I am working on a application that has a lot of data formatted in tables. I come across some plugins that would make table be more dynamic (Data Table, Tquery...). These plugin are really nice as they provide sorting and search option within a table. however I am just limited to the common style of tables with one row under an other and so on.This create an inconsistency in the user interface as the web app is mainly designed for touch screen and uses a card(tile) like interface.

What I want is to use the plugin so that I can still benefit from all the features it offers but yet be able to style the table like divs so that the rows could float against each other.
I have tried different styles, it kind of work in Firefox but not in chrome and other browsers. Thanks in advance

Any help, advice, recommandations will be really appreciated

Comment: you can set `display:block;` on the `td`s, but I think you can better look for other filter plugins that don't use tables

Comment: Oh Thanks Wouter J. Do you know any other filter that do not use tables? I guess that would be better since every browser has their own way of dealing with tables. With chrome for example I couldn't override  their default ones. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use another jQuery filter/sort plugin which don't uses tables, but lists. A favourite one is [Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html).